# Prove that $\frac aa = 1$ when $a\neq 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

We know the basic "a number $a$ divided by itself, i.e. $\frac aa$, is equal to $1.$ Except when $a=0$.

But why? How to prove this using axioms?

Comment: How is division defined?

Comment: More generally: what is your axiom set?

Comment: See [Field Axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) : axiom for multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @user1892304  You are not addressing the question.  The question does not ask why $\frac x1 = x$; it asks why for a real number $x, \;x\neq 0$, why does $\frac xx=1$?

Comment: @jordan_glen that's exactly what the user answered ... under the assumption of field axioms. Now, if OP has a different set of axioms, or wants an intuitive understanding, that needs to be specified.

Answer (score 3):

One axiom common to many systems is the multiplicative identity, $$x\cdot 1=x$$
Even in systems without a multiplicative inverse (such as integers), you can define "division" as $$\frac{a}{b}=c\iff b\cdot c=a$$
Note that this $c$ may not always exist for all pairs $a,b$ depending on your system. Working with these two assumptions, you can prove that since $x\cdot 1=x$ by the axiom, applying the definition of division with $a=x$, $b=x$, $c=1$ yields $$x\cdot 1=x\implies \frac{x}{x}=1$$
Additionally, note that $c$ may not be unique for each $a,b$ either - technically, under this definition you can show $\frac{0}{0}$ to be anything.